# Is there anything wrong with this statement? "superb hard"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

"I will have to work superb hard this week"

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please provide the full context of what you intend to say; while *superb hard* isn't necessarily wrong, it would mean something quite different from *super hard*, for example. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance on writing good, answerable questions.

Comment: @choster "superb hard" seems necessarily wrong to me: "superb" modifies nouns, now adjectives. Are there dialects in which "superb" is used as an adverb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Superb" is an adjective, not an adverb, as in

> I had a **superb** omelette this morning.

In this case, you're trying to answer the question of how hard you worked. How hard did you work? You worked ***superbly*** hard.

However, even this still sounds awkward. In common, everyday speech in the US, we would say something more like this:

> I worked **super** hard this week.

Or in a less colloquial way:

> I worked **very** hard this week.